# How to get author's display name (instead of ID number) in a WP plugin?

Tags: wordpress

This event creator plugin generates an ical file. What I want to do is change the default behavior so that the 'summary' in the ical file is the author's display name, not the ID number as it is now.

```
$output .= "SUMMARY:" . $this->escape_string( esc_attr( $event->post_author ) )
```

I'm comfortable with basic WP theme edits, but this is my first attempt at modifying a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$output .= "SUMMARY:" . get_the_author_meta('display_name',  $event->post_author) )